# Running sums for current month with cap on cumulative running total

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to create a report which contains the total transaction amounts for a particular month, but only have them appear if the total amount for that account is less than a particular cap for that account. For any fringe transactions which would pierce the cap, I would only show the portion of the amount below the cap. Below is an example.

This would have to be compatible with version 5.6.24

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE Example(
   ID int,
   Date DATE,
   AMT FLOAT(8,2)
);
INSERT INTO Example(ID, Date, AMT) 
            VALUES (1, '20190101', 1000);
INSERT INTO Example(ID, Date, AMT) 
            VALUES (1, '20190123', 1000);
INSERT INTO Example(ID, Date, AMT) 
            VALUES (1, '20190201', 1000);
INSERT INTO Example(ID, Date, AMT) 
            VALUES (2, '20180202', 2000);
INSERT INTO Example(ID, Date, AMT) 
            VALUES (2, '20190115', 1500);
INSERT INTO Example(ID, Date, AMT) 
            VALUES (2, '20190501', 1000);
INSERT INTO Example(ID, Date, AMT) 
            VALUES (2, '20190502', 750);
INSERT INTO Example(ID, Date, AMT) 
            VALUES (2, '20190505', 800);
```

The data is of the following format and assume I have a cumulative cap of 5000 per ID.

```
ID     |    Date     |    AMT     |
 1     |  1/1/2019   |   1000     |
 1     |  1/23/2019  |   1000     |
 1     |  2/1/2019   |   1000     |
 2     |  2/2/2018   |   2000     |
 2     |  1/15/2019  |   1500     |
 2     |  5/1/2019   |   1000     |
 2     |  5/2/2019   |   750      |
 2     |  5/5/2019   |   800      |
```

As of 1/31/2019, I expect to see the following result returned, which is pretty trivial:

```
ID     |    Date     |  CM_AMT    |  RUNNING
 1     |  1/1/2019   |   1000     |  1000
 1     |  1/23/2019  |   1000     |  2000
 2     |  1/15/2019  |   1500     |  3500
```

However, as of 5/31/2019, I expect to see:

```
ID     |    Date     |  CM_AMT    |   RUNNING
 2     |  5/1/2019   |   1000     |   4500
 2     |  5/2/2019   |   500      |   5000
```

Because there are no transactions for ID 1, no records should appear.
For ID 2, we have the running total from the beginning of inception. Any records after the cap has been met are dropped, hence no 5/5/2019 record. And we only record the part of a transaction before it pierces the total, ie: the 5/2/2019 record is 500 instead of 750

Comment: What is your PRIMARY KEY?

Comment: @Strawberry I did not include a primary key here b/c they are just a string of letters/numbers.

Comment: That's no reason not to provide; you can always simplify it for the example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are runing MySQL 8.0, you can do a window sum and filter by that. Then, you can use `least()` ajust the amount on the last record per id (if necessary).

```
select 
    id, 
    date, 
    least(amt, amt - running + 5000) amt,
    least(running, 5000) running
from (
    select 
        t.*,
        sum(amt) over(partition by id order by date) running
    from Example t
) t
where running - amt <= 5000
order by id, date
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=98f0b4430d5f6fd6b66039d0fb60f1f8)**:

```
id | date       |     amt | running
-: | :--------- | ------: | ------:
 1 | 2019-01-01 | 1000.00 | 1000.00
 1 | 2019-01-23 | 1000.00 | 2000.00
 1 | 2019-02-01 | 1000.00 | 3000.00
 2 | 2018-02-02 | 2000.00 | 2000.00
 2 | 2019-01-15 | 1500.00 | 3500.00
 2 | 2019-05-01 | 1000.00 | 4500.00
 2 | 2019-05-02 |  500.00 | 5000.00
```

---

In earlier versions of MySQL, you can emulate the window sum with a self-join and aggregation (or correlated subquery would also do the job):

```
select 
    id, 
    date, 
    least(amt, amt - running + 5000) amt,
    least(running, 5000) running
from (
    select t.id, t.date, t.amt, sum(t1.amt) running
    from Example t
    inner join Example t1 on t1.id = t.id and t1.date <= t.date
    group by t.id, t.date, t.amt
) x
where running - amt <= 5000
order by id, date
```

**[Demo on MySQL 5.6 DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=489ce7f5173dbe21f1966c2f5ba3fb13)**

Comment: Is there a way to do it without a windows sum?

Comment: @Farellia: why do you want to avoid window functions? Are you running a version of MySQL that does not support window functions?

Comment: I don't have direct access to this database and am running my query through a pyodbc connection. It doesn't seem to be able to handle windows functions...

Comment: @Farellia: it is not about your driver, it is about the version of your database. You can run `select version();` to see the version of your MySQL database.

Comment: Ah... I see, I'm running on 5.6.24-log

Comment: @Farellia: I updated my answer with a solution for MySQL < 5.6